# Conditionals within lambda

Tags: python, lambda

I try to initialize an array with a lambda-function called by map, and to my surprize `IF-ELSE` is not valid inside lambda.

```
a = map( (lambda x: if (len(aDict[x])==m): return aDict[x] else: return false),
         aDict.keys())
```

This is the error I get

```
File "objects.py", line 63
a = map( (lambda x: if (len(aDict[x])==m): return aDict[x] else: return false),
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the reason this does not work?

---

EDIT:

Now I discovered the interesting alternative expression

```
>>> False and 'one' or 'two'
'two'
>>> True and 'one' or 'two'
'one'
```

Very interesting... This is One-liner expression , this is why it wor

Comment: Your edit works because Python returns the last term evaluated in a boolean expression, and boolean evaluation also short-circuits when possible.  Thus `'' and 'a'` returns `''`, as an example.  This is much less clear to read than an if/else though, so unless you need it for performance reasons, it's probably not the best way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use that syntax inside a lambda, nor can you explicitly return.  Try this instead:

```
lambda x, m: aDict[x] if (len(aDict[x])==m) else False
```

Lambda functions implicitly return the value resulting from evaluating the code in them.  The code has to be expressible as a single compound expression (aka a one-liner) though.

Comment: If if-condition is true, I want it to return x. Otherwise False. How to return X ?

Comment: What I put does what you appear to have wanted from what's in your question.  If you want just `x`, use `lambda x, m: x if (len(aDict[x])==m) else False` instead.

Comment: @alinsoar You do not `return` anything from a lambda. You just  put an expression there...

Comment: Can you provide me a very link on the web where this syntax if-else inside lambda, and the limitations inside lambda are explained ?

Comment: That syntax for if/else is not specific to lambdas, it can be used anywhere.  `a = 1 if b else 2` is perfectly valid.  The point is that lambdas can only work with one-liner expressions, and that is the way you write if/else in a one-liner form.